# Remove all characters after last instance of particular character

Tags: php, string, substring

How can I remove all the content in a string after the LAST occurance of a slash character `/` ?

For example, the string is:

```
http://localhost/new-123-rugby/competition.php?croncode=12345678
```

I want to remove all the content after the last `/` so that it just shows:

```
http://localhost/new-123-rugby/
```

But the content after the `/` could be of a variable length.

Please note, there could be any number of slashes in the URL. It needs to be able to remove content after the last slash. There could be more than shown in the example above.

Comment: Is the `URL` a string or do you want to use `.htacess`?

Comment: @Rizier123 as said in the post, the URI is a string. It's $link

Comment: you can use `explode("/", $str)` will give you an array

Comment: @Alex' solution is concise and proper. You should post it as an answer.

Comment: Reference: [`parse_url`](http://php.net/manual/function.parse-url.php)

Answer (score 2):

you can try this

```
$url = "http://localhost/new-123-rugby/competition.php?croncode=12345678";
preg_match("/[^\/]+$/", $url, $matches);
$newUrl = str_replace($matches[0],'',$url);
echo $newUrl;
```

Comment: **!WRONG!** As @Francesca said in a comment: `There could be any number of slashes` and OP wants following output: `http://localhost/new-123-rugby/`, but if you have multiple slashes you don't get the Output what OP wants! See: http://ideone.com/Q9ul6Q And as you can see the output is not what OP wants!

Comment: @Rizier123, don't mind but read again. OP mention that she want to  "remove content after the last slash"

Answer (score 1):

#### Solution #1, using `substr()` + `strrpos()`:

```
$string = 'http://localhost/new-123-rugby/competition.php?croncode=12345678';
$pos = strrpos($string, '/');
if ($pos !== FALSE) {
    echo(substr($string, 0, $pos + 1));
}
```

Function [`strrpos()`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.strrpos.php) finds the position of the **last** occurrence of `/` in the string, [`substr()`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.substr.php) extracts the required substring.

**Drawback**: if `$string` does not contain `'/'`, `strrpos()` returns `FALSE` and `substr()` does not return what we want. Need to check the value returned by `strrpos()` first.

#### Solution #2, using `explode()` + `implode()`:

```
$string = 'http://localhost/new-123-rugby/competition.php?croncode=12345678';
$array  = explode('/', $string);
if (count($array) > 1) {
    array_pop($array);               // ignore the returned value, we don't need it
    echo(implode('/', $array).'/');  // join the pieces back, add the last '/'
}
```

Alternatively, instead of `array_pop($array)` we can make the last component empty and there is no need to add an extra `'/'` at the end:

```
$string = 'http://localhost/new-123-rugby/competition.php?croncode=12345678';
$array  = explode('/', $string);
if (count($array) > 1) {
    $array[count($array) - 1] = '';  // empty the last component
    echo(implode('/', $array));  // join the pieces back
}
```

**Drawback** (for both versions): if `$string` does not contain `'/'`, `explode()` produces an array containing a single value and the rest of the code produces either `'/'` (the first piece of code) or an empty string (the second). Need to check the number of items in the array produced by `explode()`.

#### Solution #3, using `preg_replace()`:

```
$string = 'http://localhost/new-123-rugby/competition.php?croncode=12345678';
echo(preg_replace('#/[^/]*$#', '/', $string));
```

**Drawbacks**: none. It works well when both when `$string` contains `'/'` and it does not contain `'/'` (it does not modify `$string` in this case).

Answer (score -3):

#### NOTA:

The question was edited so that the original answer (below the edit), doesn't match the requirements from OP. It wasn't marked as an edit from OP.

---

**EDIT:**

Updated my answer so it now matches the requirements of OP:

(Now it works with as many slashes as you want)

Will also work using
`http://localhost/new-123-rugby////////competition.php?croncode=12345678`

```
<?php

    $url = "http://localhost/new-123-rugby/competition.php?croncode=12345678";
    echo dirname($url) . "/";

?>
```

Output:

```
http://localhost/new-123-rugby/
```

---

#### Original answer:

This should work for you:

```
<?php

    $string = "http://localhost/new-123-rugby/competition.php?croncode=12345678";
    echo $string = substr($string, 0, strpos(strrev($string), "/")-2);

?>
```

Output:

```
http://localhost/new-123-rugby/
```

Demo: http://ideone.com/0R9QUG

Comment: It won't work because the value 2 is used. There could be any number of slashes. Hence why I asked for "the LAST" instance. Last instance could be 3 slashes, 8, 100...

Comment: @Francesca That would be good if you had that in your question from the start

Comment: @Rizier123 the code you provided doesn't actually work even with the content above. I have just tested it for example and it cuts off halfway through the word "competition". So it doesn't work anyway. As specified, content after the last / could be of variable length.

Comment: @Francesca Updated now my answer so it's exactly what you want and i made it so simple as possible! Also please mark edits in your question as "edit".